# SQL Query - how to translate this excel formula into a query

Tags: sql, excel, sqlite, sql-update

I have an existing excel formula.  The logic is this:

1. Start looking when dates on Table 2 "Date/Time" are greater than Table 1 "Open_Date"
2. Stop looking when dates on Table 2 "Date/Time" that are less than Table 1 "Close_Date"
3. If Table 1 "Action" says "Buy", then find where the Table 2 "Low" is less than Table 1 Column L "FixedSL".
4. If Table 1 "Action" says "Sell", then find where the Table 2 "High" is less than Table 1 Column L  "FixedSL".
5. If match is found, return the "Date/Time" in Table 2 and overwrite the value in Table 1 "Time_Hit_Fixed_SL" for that row.

Here are samples of the data tables:
Table 1

```
Open_Date,       Close_Date,   Action, FixedSL,  Time_Hit_Fixed_SL
6/1/2020 3:56,  6/1/2020 4:24,  Buy,   1.8502,   6/1/2020 5:01
6/1/2020 4:44,  6/1/2020 8:19,  Sell,  1.8411,   6/1/2020 10:12
6/1/2020 8:22,  6/1/2020 8:54,  Sell,  1.8335,   6/1/2020 10:12
```

Table 2

```
Date/Time,        Open,     High,     Low,    Close
06/01/2020 03:57,  1.8503,  1.8503,  1.8501,  1.8501
06/01/2020 03:58,  1.8501,  1.8503,  1.8501,  1.8502
06/01/2020 03:59,  1.8501,  1.8504,  1.8501,  1.8504
06/01/2020 04:00,  1.8501,  1.8505,  1.8501,  1.8503
06/01/2020 04:01,  1.8504,  1.8504,  1.8504,  1.8504
```

The forumula's output for the Table 1's first row would be 06/01/2020 03:57 overwriting the existing value in the "Time_Hit_Fixed_SL" column.

What I am looking to accomplish is to perform this same action in SQL with the data in 2 Tables.

I am new to SQL and searched, but couldn't find the right direction to obtain the guidance of where to start with writing queries to replace advanced excel formula logic.  I appreciate the help and guidance!

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.  Also tag with the database you are using.

Comment: In SQLite the only comparable text datetime format is `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`. Change the format of your dates and add also your expected output in the question to clarify what you want.

Comment: In the table, the datetime field type is Integer.  Is that correct? Please expound on what more I need to say for expected output?  Its the line after Table 2.  Let me know what more info is required.

Comment: If all the datetimes are integers then it is fine. By expected output I mean Table1 as it will be after it is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window function `MIN()` to get the value of the column `Date/Time`.

If you want a `SELECT` statement that returns your expected result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.Open_Date, t1.Close_Date, t1.Action,  
  COALESCE(
    MIN(
      CASE t1.Action
        WHEN 'Buy' THEN CASE WHEN t2.Low < t1.FixedSL THEN t2.Date_Time END
        WHEN 'Sell' THEN CASE WHEN t2.High < t1.FixedSL THEN t2.Date_Time END
      END
    )
    OVER (PARTITION BY t1.Open_Date, t1.Close_Date),
    t1.Time_Hit_Fixed_SL
  ) Time_Hit_Fixed_SL
FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
ON t2.Date_Time > t1.Open_Date AND t2.Date_Time < t1.Close_Date
```

If you want to update `Table1`:

```
UPDATE Table1 AS t1
SET Time_Hit_Fixed_SL = COALESCE(
  (
    SELECT 
      MIN(
        CASE t1.Action
          WHEN 'Buy' THEN CASE WHEN t2.Low < t1.FixedSL THEN t2.Date_Time END
          WHEN 'Sell' THEN CASE WHEN t2.High < t1.FixedSL THEN t2.Date_Time END
        END
      )
    FROM Table2 t2  
    WHERE t2.Date_Time > t1.Open_Date AND t2.Date_Time < t1.Close_Date
  ),
  t1.Time_Hit_Fixed_SL
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=b9e5f86704846d694a89e9a567f5325a).

Comment: When I run the UPDATE, it gives one error:  SQLiteStudio was unable to extract metadata from the query. Results won't be editable.  And the values are still unchanged.  Any idea what I could do to debug this?

Comment: @JonathanStearns As you can see in the demo link both queries are syntactically correct and return your expected resuts. The only thing that I changed in your sample data is the name of the column `Date/Time` to `Date_Time`, because it contains `/`. So in your code you should use `[Date/Time]` instead of to `Date_Time`.

Comment: @JonathanStearns SQLiteStudio uses an outdated version of SQLite: 3.24.0 which does not even support window functions. It's better to use another tool like DB Browser for SQLite: https://sqlitebrowser.org

Comment: @JonathanStearns For SQLite 3.24.0 this will work: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=8445e2e236ed2b25753f36aea9107d02

Comment: Thank you for the advice about DB Browser; I did not know that.  And thanks for the alternate version to match my version.  So it works now.  The problem before was the version and that in my table Date_Time and Open_Date were Integer type.  When I changed them to Text type, it worked.  Should I keep these datetime fields in Text type or is there a way for them to be Integer?  (e.g. drawbacks to them being Text type, or is this a whole different issue)

Comment: @JonathanStearns I don't see any reason for this code not to work if the dates are integers because integers are comparable. But if they are text they should be in a comparable format like `YYYY-MM-DD` which is the only valid text date format for SQLite.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't know why its not working for me.  I loaded actual data in this: [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=cf717f13e8e3aa0fc6db78bee2914422).  The output in Table 1 result should be: in line 1 "2020-06-01 04:11" and line 2 "2020-06-01 05:04".  But they are unchanged.

Comment: @JonathanStearns Change the format of your dates to YYYY-MM-DD in Table2 also, because dd/mm/yyyy is not a comparable format. Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=aa819bd70da7eabe9ca8f4f0ca08b992 It updates row 1 to 04:31 and row 2 to 05:04.

Comment: Wow, that worked.  I knew it had to be some simple oversight.  I appreciate the patience and help!  It works now

Answer (score 0):

You can use the update statement as follows:

```
update table1 t1
set t1.Time_Hit_Fixed_SL 
    = coalesce(select min(t2.date_time) 
                 from table2 t2
                where t2.date_time between t1.start_date and t2.end_Date
                  and (t1.action = 'Buy' and t2.high < t1.fixed_SL)
                       OR (t1.action = 'Sell' and t2.low < t1.fixed_SL))
                )
               ,t1.Time_Hit_Fixed_SL);
```

Comment: Thank you!  I will give that a try.  I appreciate it.

Comment: I get this: Error while executing SQL query on database 'Trade Analysis': near ".": syntax error.  When I google this, it says the code is running more than one at a time and deliminating it.  Any suggestions?